# How to Work With ControlTemplate.Triggers ,ControlTemplate.TargetType and accessing controls within ControlTemplate Using Keyboard ShortCuts

Tags: wpf, triggers, keyboard-shortcuts, controltemplate, expander

I have an usercontrol with a `LlistBox`, which has an `ItemsSource` with a Collectionview.  In order to group, I used the group style where the grouped  items will be within the `Expander` control as follows.

I want the `Exapander` with the **label content "UNKNOWN"** has to be Closed by default and rest of them should remain opened, so i have tried two methods , but none of them worked,

> 1. Using Data Trigger Within Controltemplate.Triggers
> 2. Using Data Trigger Within Controltemplate.Resources
>
> **Since the number of Expander counts varies based on the group ,Is it possible to open and close the Expander using ShortCut keys??**

for eg:If i have two Expander(Animals/Birds),using <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> i need to close or open " Exapnder Animals"

using <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> i need to close or open " Exapnder Birds"

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">




                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lbl, Path=Content}" Value="UNKNOWN">
                            <Setter Property="Expander.IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>



                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lbl, Path=Content}" Value="UNKNOWN">
                                    <Setter Property="Expander.IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                   </ControlTemplate.Resources>



                   <Expander IsExpanded="True" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"    >
                       <Expander.Header >
                           <Label x:Name="lbl"  BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="0.5"  
                                  Content="{Binding Path = Name}"  Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                  FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
                        </Expander.Header>                                   
                        <Expander.Content>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander.Content>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Datatrigger like this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lbl, Path=Content}" Value="UNKNOWN">
      <Setter TargetName="exp" Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
   </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

and name the expander:

```
<Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
...
```

Note: the expander must be defined before the trigger:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">    
   <Expander ...
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers> ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: really thanx i did some workaround way with BooleanConverter,oops thanx a lot,and if i want to open/close the dynamically generated expanders thru keyboard shortcuts,customRouted command is a rite way to apporoach?..and wat is the issue with my DataTrigger.? ans why this **`<Style.Triggers>`** didn't work? –